# Can MBrace run with the latest version of FSharp.Core?

Tags: f#, mbrace

I have tried the `MBrace Starter Kit` with no success. Then I found this post:

https://github.com/mbraceproject/MBrace.StarterKit/issues/94

I am at a point in my project where I need to do distributed computing. Is `MBrace` an alternative?